# Clojure Leiningen test FAILs not shown in error summary

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, leiningen

When running `lein test` on my current Clojure project, I got two test failures but the summary stated that I got 0 failures. See output snippet below:

```
$ lein test
FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1 (config.clj:53)
expected: (= (some-fn some-input) (expected-output))
  actual: (not (= (actual-output) (expected-output)))

FAIL in clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList@1 (config.clj:53)
expected: (= (some-fn some-other-input) (other-expected-output))
  actual: (not (= (other-actual-output) (other-expected-output)))

lein test project.test.config

lein test project.test.other-module

lein test project test.another-module

lein test project test.one-more

Ran 8 tests containing 71 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Note the `FAIL` lines and the last line. Previously tests have worked in this project, but I am unable to isolate what code changes might have affected this incorrect behavior from `lein test`.

Has anyone seen this before and know what might cause it to occur?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could provide some code in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem shortly after posting this but am leaving the question here for others. I accidentally put my test within a `def` instead of a `deftest`.